# iPhone - adjusting the date on a UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone

I have the hour and the minute as NSIntegers (I don't care about the seconds... it may be 00) and I have a UIDatePicker adjusted to display just time (UIDatePickerModeTime).

Simple question: how do I set an hour on the UIDatePicker? Hours are in the 24h format (as it comes from the picker naturally).

Suppose this:

```
NSInteger hour = 17;
NSInteger minute = 12;
[myTimePicker setDate: ????];
```

I know I have to convert that hour and minute to NSDate, but how do I do that without including a day? I just need time.

I have read [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081588/nsdate-right-way-to-work-with-time-of-day), but it also considers the day.

How do I construct a NSDate of just time, so I can adjust my UIDatePicker?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this,

```
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateComponents setHour:17];
[dateComponents setMinute:12];

myTimePicker.date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

You can later get the hour and minute like this,

```
NSCalendar * gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:myTimePicker.date];

int hour = [dateComponents hour];
int minute = [dateComponents minute];
```

Comment: Are you sure `myTimePicker` is not `nil`? I am asking this because I tested the code before submitting my answer.

Comment: it is working, thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I had a typo on the code and was using the wrong variable.