# Action based on time of day?

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, time

My application has two sets of icons, one for day and one for night.
What kind of `if-then` statement can I use to tell my app that if the time is later than `8PM-7AM`.. do this action and if it is between `7AM-8PM`.. do a different action?

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081588/nsdate-right-way-to-work-with-time-of-day

Answer (score 1):

make a day and night enum or bool ivar

When your app is launching , you can get the current time .And then you can calc whether it is day or night , and then set the enum.

Then if it is day now, you should calc the `timeInterval` from now to 8PM named timeInterval1, then make a `NSTimer` to invocation your method to change the enum to night. The delay time is timeInterval1.

```
- (void)yourmethod
{
    if(enum == day)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

More info , you can see : [How to create thread to checking time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475195/how-to-create-thread-to-checking-time/14475498#14475498)

Comment: How can I calc the time day or night? Sorry I'm very new to all this.